# Get unique objects if theres an array which is repeated in some other object in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, duplicates, unique

```
const messages = [{ id: 1, name: "Jack", users: [2,4] }, { id: 2, name: "Alex", users: [2,6] }, { id: 3, name: "John", users: [2,6] }]
```

Need to get unique object based on a nested array key. check if array containing same value is repeated in some other object and return only the last record which has the nested duplicate

expected answer =

```
[{ id: 1, name: "Jack", users: [2,4]},{id: 3, name: "John", users: [2,6] }]
```

Comment: What if `users` is `[6,2]`? Does that count as a "same" value as `[2,6]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a combined key of `users` with an object and get unique items.

```js
const
    messages = [{ id: 1, name: "Jack", users: [2, 4] }, { id: 2, name: "Alex", users: [2, 6] }, { id: 3, name: "John", users: [2, 6] }],
    result = Object.values(messages.reduce((r, o) => {
        r[o.users.join('|')] = o;
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: `[2,6]` is unique from `[6,2]`. this may be what the OP intends but seems unlikely